# Htaccess redirec issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^adminDashboard/(.*)$ ./PL_5_25_2015/index.php#admin/$1
```

this redirection rule is not able to read string after #,

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

To use anchor links (or special characters, in general) for rewritten URLs, you'd use the [**NE** flag](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/rewrite/flags#flag_ne).

```
RewriteRule ^adminDashboard/(.*)$ "PL_5_25_2015/index.php#admin/$1" [NE]
```

Comment: Hi hjpotter92, I have updated the flag but still it is not working, It redirect it to PL_5_25_2015/index.php, It does not take string after #

Comment: @AnkitRathi Try `[NE,L,R]` flags

Comment: @AnkitRathi Updated the reply. Enclosing the url in quotes should fix this.